# What should I do with the 166 items when I installed gulp locally?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, dependencies, node-modules

After I **$ npm install gulp --save-dev**

```
    npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch                       3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
    npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch                       3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
    npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and be                      fore will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to gracef                      ul-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to fi                      nd it in the tree.
    npm WARN travel-agency@1.0.0 No description
    npm WARN travel-agency@1.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN travel-agency@1.0.0 No license field.

    + gulp@3.9.1
    added 186 packages in 20.425s
```

**package.json**

```
     {
          "name": "travel-agency",
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "dependencies": {
            "jquery": "^3.2.1",
            "normalize.css": "^7.0.0"
          },
          "devDependencies": {
            "gulp": "^3.9.1"
          }       
    }
```

Is this normal? I was expecting one folder of gulp.
Is it okay to continue working with this many files?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just **dependencies for Gulp package**. And as you can see at [Gulp npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp) page, the main package has just **13 dependencies**, but each of those packages Gulp depends on have more dependencies, so I would say that 166 smaller packages for the package like Gulp are normal.

PS: By the name of the package I assume that you are working through Brad Schiff's course on Udemy :D

Comment: It is. Brad's not answering questions so I have to ask here. I am just confused since in his video he only had the gulp folder. Have you experienced the same thing? And with what you said, it means I did nothing wrong and I can continue working with this many folders ( just clarifying :D ).

Comment: I think that single Gulp folder is his folder for Gulp tasks. Anyway, I repeat that this is normal, you can continue to work on, near the end of the course you will have almost 1000 packages in the node_modules folder if I remember well. I've made [my own boilerplate](https://github.com/Puritanic/Frontend-Starter-Kit) after I finished the course and it weights right now around 1500 packages. 

By the way, if my answer clarified these things a bit for you please accept it as correct. :)

Comment: Thank you @darko ! I hope to see you in my future questions :D